# Why isn't the Response field of this HTTP Request being populated?

Tags: go, webserver, httprequest, httpresponse, http-redirect

The comment for the field `Response` in the type `http.Request` is as follows.

```
// Response is the redirect response which caused this request
// to be created. This field is only populated during client
// redirects.
Response *Response
```

However, it seems to me that this field is not being populated during requests, as it is implied that it is.  Consider the following example:

```
package main

import (
  "net/http"
  "log"
  "fmt"
)

func handleA(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
  http.Redirect(writer, request, "/b", http.StatusSeeOther)
}

func handleB(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
  fmt.Println(request.Response)
}

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/a", handleA)
  http.HandleFunc("/b", handleB)
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

If I compile and run this code and navigate to `localhost:8080/a`, then I get redirected to `localhost:8080/b` and the server prints `<nil>` to the console.  But shouldn't it be printing out a non-`nil` value, since the request is coming as the result of a redirect?

Comment: "This field is only populated during client redirects."  This is server code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample, the redirect is happening in the browser; the server doesn't get to know what response generated the redirect. That field is populated when making HTTP requests *from* a Go app; for example, if you use `http.Client` to request a URL, and the response is a redirect, it generates a new `Request` for the redirect URL, and in *that* `Request`, the `Response` field will be populated with the response that triggered that redirect.

This is evidenced in the source for `http.Client`: https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go#L669